# C# declaring a variable with the type of an expression

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I see that there are some old questions (2011) on this topic, just wondering if anything has changed that I might've missed.  The subject area is automatic type deduction, specifically when declaring variables.  The goal here is to reduce typing and hence, reduce errors, by avoiding repetition in the code.  Ideally, a solution should have zero runtime overhead and be easily understood by someone reading the code.

I have a function

```
(tuple-type-decl) Function(param-list) { body }
```

and I'd like to declare a variable

```
var list = new List<return-type-of-function>();
```

[Added] A concrete example

```
var list = new list<typeof Function(default,fault)>();
```

That is, I want the compiler to supply the type argument to List with the type that is returned by the function without my needing to retype or explicitly name that type.  I'm looking for a idiom here, not how to solve a specific use case.

Of course, I can't do that directly  in C#.  I think modern C++ would actually let me write essentially that declaration, but the C# `typeof` operator only works on types, not on expressions.  The best I've been able to come up with (and it's far from "good") is:

```
var list = (from i in Enumerable.Range(0,0) select Function(bogus-parms).ToList();
```

This in fact does declare a list of the correct type, even picking up with pseudo member names from tuple types, but it's ugggggly and very far from clear and actually has a runtime cost, albeit minimal.

Has anyone come up with a decent idiom for this construct in the C# 7/8 era?

Comment: Please, share reproducible sample. Also, how is `tuple-type-decl` related to `return-type-of-function`?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the specific types are unimportant - insert any tuple type and any parameter list and any function body you'd like.  The goal is to declare a variable that has a type based on the return type of a function, without simply re-declaring type (which might be complex or anonymous).

Comment: I should've stated more clearly in the original post - the point of the exercise is to declare the variable without repeating the definition of the type (a tuple in this example) and without making a new class for every miscellaneous tuple type that I want to return from functions.  This allows the variable declaration to evolve along with the function with less editing - add a new member to the tuple, the variable declaration is automatically correct.  And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a helper function that accepts an `Expression<Func<T>>` and then returns a `List<T>` but you'd still have to specify "bogus" parameters

```
public static List<T> ListFor<T>(Expression<Func<T>> unused)
    => new List<T>();
```

And then you'd use it like the following:

```
public static (int, string, double) MyFunc(int arg1, DateTime arg2)
{ 
    ... 
} 

var list = ListFor(() => MyFunc(default, default));
```

You can even create a list of an anonymous type (though I'm not sure why you'd want to):

```
var list = ListFor(() => new { s = "", i = 5 });
```

Comment: Nice!.  Unfortunate that it's necessary to make up a set of dummy parameters for the expression, but likely unavoidable.

Comment: This does have a bit of runtime cost as well.  It's possible that the JITer in the runtime will optimize away the instantiation of the Expression<Func<T>> instance, since it's unused.  I definitely would not use this inside a tight loop without investigating that.  As you might surmise, my purpose here is to use it outside a loop to accumulate the values returned by a function inside that same loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension method for `T`

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(this T t) => new List<T>();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/KKCDZO

Extended Version:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/MDunr1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function was declared as

```
(string name, int x, int y) Function(param-list) { body }
```

Then you can declare a list as

```
List<(string name, int x, int y)> list =
    (from i in Enumerable.Range(0,0) select Function(bogus-parms).ToList();
```

Note that I am using the new [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) type. It exists since C# 7.0 and allows you to give names to tuple fields.

You can then access items like this

```
string name = list[i].name;
int x = list[i].x;
int y = list[i].y;
```

or

```
var (name, x, y) = list[i];
Console.WriteLine($"name = {name}, x = {x}, y = {y}");
```

This is also new and is called [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation).

And of course you can create your own type

```
public readonly struct MyStruct
{
    public MyStruct(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        Name = name;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
}
```

Now the type has a name and its members have a names. You can declare a list as

```
List<MyStruct> list = ...;
```

It works also with

```
var list = ...;
```

if the expression to the right retunrs a `List<MyStruct>`, i.e., if the function has a return type of `MyStruct`. Note that the list in the second case is strongly typed as `List<MyStruct>`. Instead of declaring it explcitly, you are just letting the C# compiler inferring it. This happens as compile time and has no impact at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class which extends from your `Tuple<>` of choice. As an example you can declare a class like:

```
public class MyThing : Tuple<int, string> {
    public MyThing(int a, string b) : base(a, b) {}
}
```

Then you can use this new class `MyThing` everywhere like any other type.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var obj = Foobar("test");
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.Item2);

    IList<MyThing> list = new List<MyThing> {
        obj
    };
    Console.WriteLine(list);
}

public static MyThing Foobar(string b) {
    return new MyThing(b.Length, b);
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
(4, test)
4
test
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyThing]
```